# ajax call function is not defined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jquery's ajax function and am getting error:

> 'getQty is not defined'

Where is my mistake?

jQuery:

```
function getQty()
{
  var dataString = "itemId=" +$(".itemId").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "getQty.php",
    data: dataString,
    success:function(data)
    {
      $(".qty").val(data);
    }
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
 <a href="screen.php?itemId={$itemArray[sec].itemId}" class="btn itemId" name="itemId" onClick="getorder();">{$itemArray[sec].itemNm}</a>
```

Comment: Well the error says what's wrong...  `getQty`   is not defined. Where are you calling `getQty()`?

Comment: show some more code ... how are you making call

Comment: you're never calling `getQty()`... your link binds a different function with `onClick="getorder()`

Comment: there is no call for getQty

Comment: <a href="screen.php?itemId={$itemArray[sec].itemId}" class="btn itemId" name="itemId" onClick="getorder();"> @ASP

Comment: than what should i do to call function in link tag @FelipeSkinner

Comment: call function onClick = "getQty()"

Comment: someone already answered it :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're calling the wrong function in the HTML:

```
onClick="getorder();"
```

should be:

```
onClick="getQty();"
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is

```
$('#myLink').click(function(){  getQty(); return false; });
```

Comment: Yes this is a good practice, but it doesn't solve the issue of the function being undefined.

Comment: @TonyBarnes I have already pointed mistake in comments .. showing him best practice

Comment: @ASP I appreciate that, but an answer should be an actual answer to the issue.

Comment: guys problem is i can not get value on ajax call problem is i cant pass itemid value in data string

Comment: @TonyBarnes agreed made changes ... just in future somebody refering this question

Comment: @Prashant if Ajax call is not working is different issue ... you should accept Tony's answer